# How can I differentiate between "risk" and "danger" in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, translation

I wanted to know how to say "risk" in Japanese, so I looked it up, and found that most dictionaries translate "risk" as `「[危険]{きけん}」`.  To me, `[危険]{きけん}` means "danger", which is different.

Though, to be honest, when I thought of this, I realized that even in English, the difference is subtle. The two words feel very different, but I had to look on the net to be really sure of what that difference is.

As I see it now, "risk" is about *possibility* of danger. Danger is a certainty that you either enter into or don't.

So, if there is a sign that says "Danger, do not step on third rail", you know for sure if you step on the third rail, you get electrocuted. No two ways about it.

However, if you hear on the news that there is ice on the roads, and so it is "risky" to go out driving, you may or may not encounter ice, and it may or may not be a problem.

So, as far as I translate it in Japanese,　`[危険]{きけん}` is definite danger (correct me if I'm wrong about that). If I see a sign that says `「[危険]{きけん}　ー　[入]{はい}らないでください」`, I expect that if I enter, something *definitely* dangerous will occur.

If I wanted to express "risk" in Japanese, is there a word I can use? Do I have to say something like `「[危険]{きけん}の[可能性]{かのうせい}」`?

Specifically, the kind of situation I imagine this in is financial risk. Like in a business meeting where I'd want to say "I would rather not take on that risk."

Lastly, I know I could maybe use `リスク`, but using katakana makes me sad.

Comment: No difference, there are the same word in Japanese in term of "dangerous". You can express the risk of possiblity with 可能性 though.

Comment: I would simple say `リスク`. If you don't want to use katakana, `危険性{きけんせい}` might be good.

Comment: @DaveMG san, Lol why does using katakana make you sad?

Comment: @rio san why do you spell Engrish speakar?

Comment: @Chocolate プロファイルのことですか？すいません、あれ冗談のつもりです。英語の下手な日本人が喋る英語を Engrish というらしいので。

Comment: You have 'risk, danger, peril, hazard, caution' etc... But we can use just 危険(or恐れ?) for most of them, and we would need some explanation to understand the difference and to know which one to use in what context. Like... we have 米、ご飯、米飯、白米、稲、ライス、もみ etc... while you can just say 'rice' to refer to them.

Comment: @rio san, うふふ！おもしろい・・^^

Comment: To add to @rio's comment, looking up `危険性` on the dictionary in OSX goes straight to the Wikipedia entry for `リスク`.

Comment: Yeah katakana makes me sad too, especially if there's a valid non-katakana word for it. But in this case…

Comment: Everybody, please... comments are not for answers: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/593/comments-are-not-for-answers

Comment: @Chocolate: Because it makes me feel like I'm not *really* speaking Japanese, but faking it with my own language.

Comment: @DaveMG Ah really...well I usually don't feel you're faking or anything when I hear a non-Japanese person use a katakana-word... especially when you pronounce it the way we do, like... 'Risuku', not 'risk'. --- Lol I've just noticed no one's posted an answer yet.

Comment: @Chocolate: I understand that katakana words aren't *really* faking anything. They're now as much a part of Japanese as words of French or Latin origin are proper English words. Still, I just can't help feeling a distance between myself and the Japanese language when I use borrow words. I wouldn't go so far as to say 写真機 instead of カメラ, but I prefer to use words of Japanese origin when possible.

Comment: @Chocolate: Also: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/639/you-dont-have-to-get-a-green-check-to-be-right-or-to-be-helpful

Comment: @DaveMG san, 写真機 lol!

Comment: Dave M G, to avoid katakana because it's not Japanese is a very Western way of thinking. If you want to really feel Japanese, one way is to use katakana words the way Japanese use them, not as they are used in English. For example, if you say 仕事のパワー, you are using パワー in a very Japanese way to mean 'ability'. This is katakana, but it's definitely not English. So, it's not the use of katakana that should be a problem, it's how you use it!

Comment: @Bathrobe: It is a very western way of thinking. I am from a (so-called) western culture, and I have no ambitions to change that. You make a fair point that katakana as used in Japanese is distanced from English meanings anyway. But I'm content to avoid them because it's a choice that represents me. The goal is not to shed my way of thinking in order to speak Japanese better, it's to speak Japanese better to express how I think.

Comment: @Chocolate: If you put your comments into an answer, I have a strong feeling they would be marked as correct...

Comment: @DaveMG san Ah thanks, well I'm still not sure if I can do very well but I'll try anyway

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have 'risk, danger, peril, hazard, caution' etc... But we can use just 危険(or恐れ?) for most of them, and we would need some explanation to understand the difference and to know which one to use in what context. Like... we have 米、ご飯、米飯、白米、稲、ライス、もみ etc... while you can just say 'rice' to refer to them.　
 As rio-san and istrasci-san said, I think 'risk' can be referred to as [危険性]{きけんせい} as well as just 'リスク'. 
When you'd want to talk about 'financial risk', like 'I would rather not take on that risk,' I'd rather use 'リスク' though・・・→ http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RURgbNJZ6rA&feature=pyv -- at 2:45, 3:45. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABvLOW_nEh8&feature=related -- at 1:37, 1:43, 2:39, 2:59 etc...